# get sim serial using telephonymanager

Tags: android

i am able to get my sim card's serial using telephonymanager, the code works fine. However, it force closes if there is no sim card inserted, so is there any way to handle this exception?

```
    private void getAndSaveCurrentID(View view) {
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    // ---get first time SIM card ID ---
    String simID = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
    if (simID != null)
        Toast.makeText(this, "current SIM card ID: saved " + simID,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("Name", simID.toString());
    editor.commit();
}

02-14 11:27:42.643: E/AndroidRuntime(9674): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 11:27:42.643: E/AndroidRuntime(9674): Process: com.air.bgusatm, PID: 9674
02-14 11:27:42.643: E/AndroidRuntime(9674): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method getAndSaveCurrentID(View) in the activity class com.air.bgusatm.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'
```

will it work if i surround it with a try cache block?

Answer (score 0):

```
String simID = null;
try{
    simID = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
}catch(Exception e){
}finally{
 if (simID != null)
    Toast.makeText(this, "current SIM card ID: saved " + simID,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("Name", simID.toString());
editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: its throwing null when it does not have sim card

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `getAndSaveCurrentID(View)` in the onClick method of your button passing `view` as parameter remove the parameter and everything should work. Your method `getAndSaveCurrentID()` does not have any parameter.

```
 private void getAndSaveCurrentID() {
    try{
       TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    // ---get first time SIM card ID ---
    String simID = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
    if (simID != null)
        Toast.makeText(this, "current SIM card ID: saved " + simID,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("Name", simID.toString());
    editor.commit();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("Error","error ocurred");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i know, i removed it just to test exception handelling, it force closes if there is no sim card

Answer (score 0):

You can check SIM is Absent or not.

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if(telephonyManager.getSimState()!= TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT)
        {
            //your code here
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my sollution, it detects if there is a sim card first then calls my method, feel free to edit my answer!

```
public void SimDetectorForGetAndSaveCurrentId(View view) {// save serial
    // fire only if there is sim card inserted
    TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    int simState = telMgr.getSimState();
    switch (simState) {
    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "please make sure you have a SIM card inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_NETWORK_LOCKED:
        getAndSaveCurrentID();
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED:
        getAndSaveCurrentID();
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED:
        getAndSaveCurrentID();
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY:
        getAndSaveCurrentID();
        break;
    case TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_UNKNOWN:
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "please make sure you have a SIM card inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the exception that you get with this code? please post your logcat or you receive the first posted :(